# android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout has leaked:

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm using LeakCanary to detect memory leaks in an app. I successfully identified and fixed some leaks using it, but I am struggling find the root of this leak:

```
* android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout has leaked:
* Toast$TN.mNextView
* ↳ LinearLayout.mContext
* ↳ HomeActivity.!(mDelegate)!
* ↳ AppCompatDelegateImplN.!(mActionBar)!
* ↳ ToolbarActionBar.!(mDecorToolbar)!
* ↳ ToolbarWidgetWrapper.!(mToolbar)!
* ↳ Toolbar.mParent
* ↳ ConstraintLayout
* Reference Key: 552b5bc5-409d-44c4-8412-87341237ae6d
* Device: samsung samsung SM-G960F starltexx
* Android Version: 8.0.0 API: 26 LeakCanary: 1.6.2 0ebc1fc
* Durations: watch=5769ms, gc=153ms, heap dump=933ms, analysis=5802ms
```

Is this leak caused by the Android SDK or app specific code?

Comment: Looks like **context** is leaked from your **constraint layout**, check for it if you're using it as **root view**.

Comment: I believe this leak is caused by the App's specific code. Can you please paste your code as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The leak was caused by app specific code. One fragment called `getActivity().setSupportActionBar()` with a view contained in the fragments layout. When switching to another fragment the resources couldn't get gc'ed because the activity was still holding a reference to the no longer visible toolbar.
I fixed this leak by calling `getActivity().setSupportActionBar(null)` in the fragments `onDestroyView()` method, which removes the reference to the toolbar.