# onCreateOptionsMenu is not called if supportActionBar is null before fragment onCreate

Tags: android

If I have one activity with one fragment, *fragment1*, and use the navigation component to navigate from *fragment1* to *fragment2* after setting the supportActionBar to null in onDestroyView, `onCreateOptionsMenu` is not called even if `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` is called in onCreate.

### fragment1.kt:

```kotlin
...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar) //kotlin view extension to the Toolbar in fragment1.xml
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.without_toolbar_button).setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(null)
    }
...
```

### fragment2.kt:

```kotlin
...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "onCreateOptionsMenu called!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //this is never called if navigation occurs from fragment1 to this fragment.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }
...
```

### fragment1.xml & fragment2.xml:

```xml
...
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... />
...
```

The toast is never called. A full demo project demonstrating this can be found and cloned on [github](https://github.com/Frans-Lukas/OnCreateOptionsMenuNotCalledDemo/tree/master).

"I had problems with fragments remaining in memory. After adding setSupportActionBar(null), the fragments were garbage collected." See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53409237/14053602) from a thread about memory leaks.

Comment: Why you are using setSupportActionBar(null) ?

Comment: Oh, forgot about adding that. I had problems with fragments remaining in memory. After adding setSupportActionBar(null), the fragments were garbage collected.

Comment: Which one? `onCreate`? Moving `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to `onViewCreated` changes nothing.